# keep getting invalid identifier and incorrect datatype in apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
create table Schedule (
lms_code   varchar (100),
bcode      varchar (100),
start_date varchar (100),
end_date   varchar (100),
timings    time
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you'd

- use `VARCHAR2` datatype (not `VARCHAR`). Why? Oracle says

  > The VARCHAR datatype is synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. To avoid possible changes in behavior, always use the VARCHAR2 datatype to store variable-length character strings.
- `start_date` and `end_date` should be `DATE`, not `VARCHAR2`. **Always** store dates into `DATE` datatype column, **never** store them as strings into `VARCHAR2`. Why? Today is 6th of November 2020 and you'd store it into `DATE` datatype column as e.g. date literal: `date '2020-11-06'`. If it were a `VARCHAR2` column, you could put `06.11.2020` into it, or `1f.scx3.f4`, or `Littlefoot` ... all those are *strings* and you'll have problems if you insist on storing dates as strings.
- as of the `timings` column, question is: what will you store in there? There's no `time` datatype in Oracle so you'd use `date` (if you're happy with times up to seconds), `timestamp` (if you need fractional seconds), or ... I don't know, something else - again, depending on what you'll be storing into that column

So: to make it work, you could

```
SQL> create table Schedule (
  2    lms_code   varchar2 (100),
  3    bcode      varchar2 (100),
  4    start_date date,
  5    end_date   date,
  6    timings    date
  7  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong data type , we don't have time datatype , you can use   `TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule
    (
        lms_code     VARCHAR(100)
        , bcode      VARCHAR(100)
        , start_date VARCHAR(100)
        , end_date   VARCHAR(100)
        , timings    TIMESTAMP
    );
```